# Umbraco Media Via Cloudinary

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7, cloudinary

I've been trying to change Umbraco so the media is provided via Cloudinary.

What I have done so far is make a new IFileSystem

Here's a small snippet:

```
public CloudinaryFileSystem()
    {
        var account = new Account(
            "account",
            "key",
            "secret");
        _cloudinary = new CloudinaryDotNet.Cloudinary(account);

    }
    public IEnumerable<string> GetDirectories(string path)
    {
        var test = "test";
        return new List<string>{test};
    }
```

I've also updated the FileSystemProvider.config:

```
 <!-- Media -->
<Provider alias="media" type=" Extensions.CloudinaryFileSystem, Extensions">
    <Parameters>
    </Parameters>
  </Provider>
```

I've also added the media path location in the web.config:

```
<location path="media">
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="StaticFileHandler" />
    <add name="StaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
 </location>
```

Now when I run the project I can upload a new image:

[image]

When I upload an image it hits my custom file provider and uploads the file to Cloudinary

Code:

```
public void AddFile(string path, Stream stream)
    {
        ImageUploadParams prmas = new ImageUploadParams();

        var folder = path.Split('\\')[0];
        var name = path.Split('\\')[1];

        prmas.Folder = "media/" + folder;

        prmas.UseFilename = true;
        prmas.File = new FileDescription(name, stream);

        _cloudinary.Upload(prmas);
    }
```

The issue I have now is that when looking at the media in Umbraco it still comes from the local media, I have all the methods implemented for IFileSystem but only a could of them are hit when I browser the media in Umbraco.

At the moment I'm just playing around so the code is a bit dirty. But I can't see why it's not working.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue with this, The methods are there to get the file information in order to set it for Umbraco. They are not used to get the file information after the upload.